# Getting the size of a QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I want to know the size of a certain `QGraphicsView`. Its size isn't fixed because the widget is part of a grid layout. I tried using `this->ui->myGraphicsView->width()` and its height equivalent but these values aren't accurate.

How can I get the current size of a `QGraphicsView`?

Comment: May you want to know size of `QGraphicsView->viewport()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constantly received 100x30 as the size of my QGraphicsView as well. It turned out I was asking for the size of the QGraphicsView before it was shown.

After moving my initialization code to showEvent, I got the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna know the actual size of QGraphicsView, QGraphicsView::size();
If you wanna konw only the content size of QGraphicsView, QGraphisView::viewport().size();

Comment: `QGraphicsView::size()` (width 100, height 30) and `QGraphics::viewport()` (width 94, height 24) both seem to report an incorrect size. I'm trying to retrieve the width/height in MainWindow's constructor - does that pose an issue? `ui->setupUi(this);` is called before I try to retrieve the size.

Comment: Try this => 
ui->graphicsView->geometry().width()

Comment: I'm still getting width 100, height 30.

Comment: I tried the following functions:

size()
viewport()
geometry()
sizeHint()
sizeIncrement()
sceneRect()
baseSize()
sizeHint()
frameSize()
rect()
normalGeometry()

QAbstractScrollArea *area = qobject_cast<QAbstractScrollArea*>(ui->graphicsView);
area->size()

But the results still don't seem right.

Answer (score 2):

> retrieve the width/height in MainWindow's constructor

That is the problem! The widget isn't painted already and you're asking for it's size. Use other events like `event`, `showEvent`, `paintEvent` to get the right size within the initialization process of a widget.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
 After calling MainWindow::show(), then get the size.

Description:
 I had the same problem as Pieter. In the widget constructor like MainWindow::MainWindow() you can't get the correct size of the widget like QGraphicsView in Grid Layout because in that constructor the widget's size and location are not determined. Therefore, in MainWindow::MainWindow() you have to call show() and then get the size of the view or other widget.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you. `QGraphicsView.size()` is always `return (100,30)`. I have solved this problem in my project.

Check below code is like this

```
...in a QTabWidget class...
def addANewTab(self):
  view = QGraphicsView()
  ...set view param...
  index = self.addTab(view, 'test')
  view.size() # it will return (100,30)
  self.setCurrentIndex(index)
  view.size() # it will return correct size
```

so like Bigbell Mercy answered , you show make sure `QGraphicsView` is show!