# QGraphicsView size in a GridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I have found this: [Getting the size of a QGraphicsView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103613/getting-the-size-of-a-qgraphicsview)

But I can't figure out what does it mean to "move my initialization code to showEvent" and I can't comment on that answer.

I am want to resize a QPixmap so it could fit my QGraphicsView. I've placed my graphicsview in Designer and set GridLayout for my main window. In a MainWindow constructor I have written the following code:
   ui->setupUi(this);

```
// Get GView size
g_sizeX = ui->mapView->width();
g_sizeY = ui->mapView->height();
// Init  scene
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
// Init MAP pixmap and add it to scene
mapImage = new QPixmap(":/Map/europe.jpg");
QPixmap newmapImage = mapImage->scaled(g_sizeX, g_sizeY);
scene->addPixmap(newmapImage);

// Display scene in gview.
ui->mapView->setScene(scene);
```

But I always get size of 100x30. If I break the gridLayout, I get the correct size.
So, how should I deal with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QGraphicsView` will be resized by the `QGridLayout` after the widget is shown, and can be also resized later when the window is itself resized.

So you should change the size of the pixmap as a result of a `QResizeEvent`, either by subclassing `QGraphicsView` to redefine `resizeEvent()`, and then promoting your view object to your new class in the designer to use it instead of `QGraphicsView`, or by installing your `MainWindow` object as an event filter for the view to handle to the resize event from the `MainWindow::eventFilter` function.

You probably don't want to change the pixmap size in the scene, but rather adjust the view matrix so that your `QGraphicsPixmapItem` fits perfectly inside the view, with [`QGraphicsView::fitInView`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView).

For example:

```
/* QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixmapItem; as a MainWindow member */
pixmapItem = scene->addPixmap(newmapImage);

/* Either always disable or enable the scrollbars (see fitInView doc) */
ui->mapView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
ui->mapView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

ui->mapView->installEventFilter(this);
...
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *evt) {
     if(obj == ui->mapView && evt->type() == QEvent::Resize) { 
          ui->mapView->fitInView(pixmapItem, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
     }
     // Call the base class implementation 
     return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, evt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what is happening is that Qt only applies layouts and sets widget sizes when the widget is first displayed.

One way to work that is to override QWidget::showEvent(), and put your sizing code in there.

However, one simpler way, that *often* works in constructors, is to ask the widget for its sizeHint(), rather than for its not-yet-layed-out size.

In your case, that would mean changing two lines of code to:

```
g_sizeX = ui->mapView->sizeHint().width();
g_sizeY = ui->mapView->sizeHint().height();
```

If your layout isn't too complicated, and if you haven't overridden the default size policies, this may well fix things for you.