PyQt: Change Postion of QInputDialog (PyQt6)
Trying to use a QInputDialog to get some input, and I would like it to appear at the mouse cursor. I'v tried this, but it doesn't seem to work; the dialog box appears in the same position every time.
def createNewNote(self):
    cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
    input_dialog = QInputDialog(self)
    input_dialog.setWindowTitle("New Note")
    input_dialog.setLabelText("Enter Note Name:")
    input_dialog.setGeometry(cursor_pos.x(), cursor_pos.y(), input_dialog.width(), input_dialog.height())
    ok = input_dialog.exec()
    if ok:
        title = input_dialog.textValue()
        note_node = NoteNode(self)
        note_node.move(cursor_pos)
        note_node.setTitle(title)
        self.note_nodes.append(note_node)
        note_node.show()

Note that this works fine for the other object.
QInputDialog .move() and .setGeometry() methods seem to do nothing.

Could it be caused by widget moving out of screen when repozitioned ?

By default dialogs are always centered on the window of the parent widget (or the screen). You could create a subclass, then override showEvent(), call the base implementation and then call setGeometry().

@musicamante , my reduced script works fine with me . I suspect It could be a glitch  using some other parent/child stuff the OP doesnt show us

exec_ is removed from pyqt6

@pippo1980 After checking the sources again, I realized that if the geometry is set before showing, it should be preserved. Still, the window manager may choose to ignore that and show the window wherever it wants, based on its configuration.

@koren69 That code should work as expected, but it's impossible to be 100% sure since the code is partial. Please provide a complete [mre] and also add information about your environment: Qt (not PyQt) version, OS, display configuration, etc. Note that if you're on Linux using Wayland, it's not possible to do that as Wayland prevents top level windows to set their own position.

My attempt :
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
                      QApplication,
                      QMainWindow,
                      QInputDialog,
                      QPushButton,
)

from PyQt6.QtGui import QCursor 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWin(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__() # 
        
        self.cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
        
        self.setGeometry(self.cursor_pos.x(),self.cursor_pos.y(), 400 , 400)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWin")
        
        self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
        
        self.button1.setText('open QInputDialog')
        
        #self.button1.move(180, 180) # or
        
        self.button1.setGeometry(130, 180, 200, 100)
        
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.input_dialog_show)
        
        
        #self.show()  #redundant for below window.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print("event", e)
        if e.key()  == Qt.Key_Return :
            print(' return')
            
            self.input_dialog_show()
        
        
    def input_dialog_show(self):
        
        input_dialog = QInputDialog(self)
        input_dialog.setWindowTitle("New Note")
        input_dialog.setLabelText("Enter Note Name:")
        input_dialog.resize(400 , 100)

        self.cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
        
        input_dialog.setGeometry(self.cursor_pos.x(), self.cursor_pos.y(), input_dialog.width(), input_dialog.height())
        
        input_dialog.parent().showMinimized()
        
        print('input_dialog_parent() : ', input_dialog.parent(), type(input_dialog.parent()))
        
        input_dialog.show()
        # ok = input_dialog.exec()
        # if ok:
            # title = input_dialog.textValue()
            # note_node = NoteNode(self)
            # note_node.move(cursor_pos)
            # note_node.setTitle(title)
            # self.note_nodes.append(note_node)
            # note_node.show()
        
       
if __name__== '__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) # Create an instance of QtWidgets.QApplication
    
    window = MainWin() # Create an instance of our class
    
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Just move the mouse cursor far from MainWin and hit Return key , you should get the QInputDialog where  ther cursor is. So your code snippet is working with me, without a MRE ( How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example  ) I cannot try to do more
I am adding the override showEvent method version too :
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
                      QApplication,
                      QMainWindow,
                      QInputDialog,
                      QPushButton,
)


from PyQt6.QtGui import QCursor 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt



class QInputDialog_MOD(QInputDialog):
    
    def showEvent(self, event):
        
        print('showed...............................')
        
        # super().showEvent(event) # ** not needed see below but better putting it anyway
        
        self.cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
        
        # self.move(0,0)
        
        self.move(self.cursor_pos.x(),self.cursor_pos.y())
        
        
        """
        ** not needed  :
            
            
            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758523/how-to-properly-override-showevent-for-qwidget-or-qmainwindow-should-super-alw
            
            In your particular case since you are overriding the showEvent method of MainForm that inherits directly from 
            QWidget that does nothing according to the source code it does not matter if you call the showEvent method 
            (although it is recommended that you call super() as good practice), it does not matter either that you add 
            the functionality before or after super.
            
            https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.14/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp#L9814
        
        """
        # super().showEvent(event)   # not needed  **
        


class MainWin(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__() # 
        
        
        self.cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
        
        self.setGeometry(self.cursor_pos.x(),self.cursor_pos.y(), 400 , 400)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWin")
        
        self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
        
        
        self.button1.setText('open QInputDialog')
        
        # self.button1.move(180, 180)
        
        # self.button1.move(0, 0)
        
        # self.button1.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 100)
        
        self.button1.setGeometry(130, 180, 200, 100)
        
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.input_dialog_show)
        
        
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print("event", e)
        if e.key()  == Qt.Key_Return :
            print(' return')
            
            self.input_dialog_show()
        
        
    def input_dialog_show(self):
        
        input_dialog = QInputDialog_MOD(self)
        input_dialog.setWindowTitle("New Note")
        input_dialog.setLabelText("Enter Note Name:")
        
        input_dialog.resize(400 , 100)
        
        # self.cursor_pos = QCursor.pos()
        
        # input_dialog.setGeometry(self.cursor_pos.x(), self.cursor_pos.y(), input_dialog.width(), input_dialog.height())
        
        
        input_dialog.parent().showMinimized()
        
        print('input_dialog_parent() : ', input_dialog.parent(), type(input_dialog.parent()))
        
        
        input_dialog.show()
        # ok = input_dialog.exec()
        # if ok:
            # title = input_dialog.textValue()
            # note_node = NoteNode(self)
            # note_node.move(cursor_pos)
            # note_node.setTitle(title)
            # self.note_nodes.append(note_node)
            # note_node.show()
        
        
if __name__== '__main__':
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) # Create an instance of QtWidgets.QApplication
    
    window = MainWin() # Create an instance of our class
    
    # window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())

in the hope its implementation is correct , see relevant and
really informative SO post about it :
how to properly override showEvent for QWidget or QMainWindow ? Should super always be called, and if so, how?

I have no idea, you said my code works for you? Neither or your examples worked for me, or stripping down my code. I'm on Linux, if that matters at all.

quoting @musicamante [44654 rep ; pyqt5 1,543 Score 1,311 Posts 69 Posts %] "@koren69 That code should work as expected, but it's impossible to be 100% sure since the code is partial. Please provide a complete minimal reproducible example and also add information about your environment: Qt (not PyQt) version, OS, display configuration, etc. Note that if you're on Linux using Wayland, it's not possible to do that as Wayland prevents top level windows to set their own position."

@koren69 You never provided proper environment details even if they were asked, but considering the whole context we can assume that what I already wrote in my comment to your original post (also quoted by pippo1980 above) is probably correct: there is no way to set the window geometry if you're using Wayland, at least in its current implementation. That's how it works right now, and we cannot do anything about it except for being aware about it. In case you're absolutely sure you're not using Wayland, then [edit] your question and provide a [mre] as requetsed.
